# Is there any way to access the GeoJSON of a Google Maps tile?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geojson

The Google Maps styling options provided by the JavaScript API are not sufficient for my needs. I would like to access the raw data and use the coordinates to have the map drawn by my application. I have looked through the API and although it appears there's what they call the Data Layer, it seems like that's only for loading my own data into one of their maps.

Is this possible with Google Maps (or any other major provider)? I am currently using OpenStreetMap but their data is woefully inadequate.

Comment: If the downvoter could explain how I could narrow the scope of the question or otherwise make it a better fit for this community, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm simply asking if there's a method I may have missed or misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps doesn't have any method to retrieve a tile imagery as GeoJSON.

Additionally, there is a following restriction in [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

> No derivative works. You will not modify or create a derivative work based on any Content unless expressly permitted to do so under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; or (iii) tracing or copying the copyrightable elements of Google’s maps or building outlines and creating a new work, such as a new mapping or navigation dataset.

So you cannot modify tile imagery outside the Google Maps service.